# Laravel get values from collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If collection is created from an array:

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->push([
        'var1'=>'value1',
        'var2'=>'value2'
       ]);
```

is there possibility to get value for specific key similar way to eloquent collection attributes?

```
$collection->var1
```

Comment: Here you have not created a collection from Array, what you did is pushed a whole array into the collection, are you only going to use this array in the collection? or you wanna push more arrays afterwards that might have same keys?

Answer (score 4):

My variant:

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->push([
    'var1'=>'value1',
    'var2'=>'value2'
]);
$value = $collection->get('var1'); // value1
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-get

Comment: This does not work at least in laravel 8 because you push an array to the collection.
You probably wanted to write:
$collection->get(0)['var1'];

Answer (score 2):

There is few methods for collection of objects

```
$collection->pluck('name')->first(); // get first name attribute

$collection->firstWhere('name', 'Mark')?->name // search by name. get attribute or null
$collection->where('name', 'Mark')->first()?->name
```

If collection of structure key => value (like in the question) just use ->get()

```
$collection->get('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can definitely do something like

```
$collection->first(function($value, $key) {
  return $key == 'var1';
});
```

or simply what @AlexeyMezenin suggested.

```
$collection[0]['var1'];
```

Answer (score -1):

To set a key'd value in a collection you can use the `put()` method.

```
$collection = collect();

$collection->put("var1", "value1");
$collection->put("var2", "value2");
$collection->put("var3", "value3");
```

To push just a value without a key to the collection, use the `push()` method, like you did in the OP.

```
$collection->push("value4");
```

To retrieve those value, use `get()` method;

```
$collection->get("var2");
```

Want to see the contents of the collection? Use the `dd()` method on the collections instances. Both of the following work.

```
dd($collection)
```

or

```
$collection->dd()
```

Comment: Because none of them use Laravel Collection Methods

Comment: Okay, initially I thought it was posted two months ago. Got my dates mixed up

Answer (score -2):

My personal touch though I am still learning the basics myself so don't shoot me down for trying! I know its a little extra code but from experience you can get caught out with offset exception errors when calling `$collection[0]` explicitly (Hope I am making sense as this has been a personal gotcha experience)

My approach would be the following

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->push([
    'var1'=>'value1',
    'var2'=>'value2'
]);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($collection); $x++) {
    if (isset($collection[$x])) {
        $var = $collection[$x];
    }
}

// Now call what ever variable from the collection you wish:

echo $var['var1'];
echo $var['var2'];
```

Hope that helps, Like I said though I am far from experienced with php/laravel and I am still learning from research myself :)

Comment: Just use method ->toArray() on collection. That method transform collection to array instead of custom for loop